# Find the smallest value of $n$ so that the greater potency of $5$ which divides $n!$ is $5^{84}$. What are the other numbers that enjoy this property?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, factoring, factorial, prime-factorization

> Find the smallest value of $n$ so that the greater potency of $5$ which divides $n!$ is $5^{84}$. What are the other numbers that enjoy this property?

I thought I would put together an equation of the type $$E_5(n!)=84\\84=\left[\frac{n}{5} \right]+\left[\frac{n}{5^2} \right]+\left[\frac{n}{5^3} \right]+\;...$$
Only I do not see how to proceed, or if this path will take me where I want, someone could help me?

Answer (score 5):

You have

$$E_p(n!) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \left\lfloor \frac{n}{p^k}\right\rfloor < \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{n}{p^k} = \frac{n}{p} \sum_{r=0}^\infty \frac{1}{p^r} = \frac{n}{p}\frac{1}{1-\frac1p} = \frac{n}{p-1},$$

and the difference is small(ish). The first sum is actually finite, all terms for $k > \frac{\log n}{\log p}$ are $0$, writing it as an infinite sum is just convenient.

So to have $E_p(n!) = m$, a ball-park estimate is $n \approx (p-1)\cdot m$, and we must have $n > (p-1)\cdot m$. For $p=5$ and $m = 84$, that yields $n \approx 4\cdot 84 = 336$.

The smallest $n$ will of course be a multiple of $5$, so let's check $n = 340$:

$$E_5(340!) = 68 + 13 + 2 = 83,$$

which is a little too small, we need one more power, so $n = 345$ is it.

Comment: For the first sum $k$ goes to infinity?$$$$I do not understand why the summations.

Comment: Since you take the floor, all terms become $0$ when $p^k > n$, we could write finite bounds, $$\sum_{k=1}^{\left\lfloor \frac{\log n}{\log p}\right\rfloor} \left\lfloor \frac{n}{p^k}\right\rfloor,$$ that would be the same result. Writing an upper bound of $\infty$ is just simpler.

Comment: Ah, interesting, I did this because it can be infinite.
However, because $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{n}{p^k} = \frac{n}{p-1}?$$

Comment: Geometric series. Just added one more step to show it.

Comment: Ah yes, how $$\frac{1}{p}<1$$ the series converges for $$\frac{\frac{1}{p}}{1-\frac{1}{p}}=\frac{1}{p-1}$$

Comment: What are other numbers that have this same property?

Comment: If $n$ is a multiple of $5$, the highest power of $5$ dividing $n!$ is greater than the highest power of $5$ dividing $(n-1)!$. If $n$ is not a multiple of $5$, the highest power of $5$ dividing $n!$ is also the highest power of $5$ dividing $(n-1)!$. So if $345$ is the smallest $n$ with $5^{84}$ dividing $n!$ but $5^{85}$ not dividing $n!$, the other numbers with this property are - can you figure it out from the above?

Comment: There is only this number with this property?

Comment: What is the highest power of $5$ dividing $346!$ by the above?

Comment: $$5^{84}$$
Ah yes, then it would be all factorial number greater than $345$ that is not multiple of five?

Comment: Until the next multiple of $5$. From $350!$ on, we have at least $5^{86}$ dividing $n!$.

Comment: So we have the numbers that have this same property are $346!,347!,348!$ and $349!$.

Comment: And not to forget, the smallest, $345!$.

Comment: Really, really good, Thanks a lot!